# Issues expanding subnet from /24 to /21

Tags: subnet, design

I've read the posts already here about increasing a subnet and the various possible issues including broadcast traffic. But those examples seem to be a drastic change from a /24 to a /16. What about if it's just from a /24 to a /21 and the DHCP pool itself is still a /24? Would going from 250 IP's to 2000 IP's really make that big of a difference?

Comment: You probably need to add more specifics to your question. Going from 256 IP addresses to 2048 would make a difference of 8 times the potential devices on the network, roughly. That is a very large difference. Imagine if your home suddenly had 8 times more bedrooms and bathrooms and kitchen space, etc. As for the DHCP pool, if you have a need to increase the network from /24 to /21, it is likely you would increase the DHCP pool as well, at least by double if not more. Did you have some other specific question?

Comment: The DHCP pool would stay /24 and I wouldn't be increasing the amount of devices on the network either. There's about 175 devices on the network now and going to a /21 is mostly for organization; just moving like devices on a similar IP range.

Comment: That idea doesn't really make any sense unless you have a single network with like 800 servers with manual IP configuration and 200 user devices who use those servers and need DHCP. 'Organization' implies categorization or segmentation. If you need those, then you need a separate network segment, likely via implemenation of VLANs.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your network - a 100 Mbit/s segment with 2000 hosts could get significantly loaded with broadcast traffic, depending on the (application layer) protocols you're running.

With low broadcast volume, 2000 hosts isn't a problem technically, but it may be organizationally and it may be relevant in the security/zoning context as well.

Comment: For clarification: the DHCP pool would stay /24 and I wouldn't be increasing the amount of devices on the network either. There's about 175 devices on the network now and going to a /21 is mostly for organization; just moving like devices on a similar IP range. There's a Guest Wifi network but that would in it's own zone and it would be a /23, so that's 500 out of the 2k IP's.

Comment: That sounds like you'd really need multiple subnets to zone your network. Putting everything in one subnet isn't zoning.

Comment: Yeah, increasing the size of the network but not the DHCP pool, does nothing increase your potential for problems. Your guest wifi should already be on its own VLAN or isolated network (assuming the main network is business, etc.) so no need to increase the main network at all. Increase the guest wifi network or simply add a vlan for a second guest wifi if desired. 500 on a single wifi network already implies enterprise level equipment so VLANs are a given.